# Сколько примерно пользователей может скрываться за forward-прокси (с одним IP-адресом)?

Tags: сеть, ip, proxy

Хотя бы примерно. Насколько распространена такая практика? Я себе это примерно представляю как максимум 100 пользователей в каком нибудь офисе.

Comment: Много... Если под натом, или динам ип, могут быть десятки.

Comment: @And Сколько? Сотни? Тысячи? Динамический ip это же другое.

Comment: Если прокси сервер (тогда все соединения идут не с адресов пользователей, а с адреса это прокси сервера).

Comment: @And Ну разумеется, я как бы про это и спрашиваю.

Comment: Там могут быть миллионы пользователей. И нельзя делать предположений, что их там какое-то определённое число.

Comment: @zed Приходится делать предположения. Я как раз настраиваю лимиты скорости обработки запросов на веб-сервере с ключом в виде IP пользователя. По-моему мильоны - это перебор.

Comment: Какое бы предположение вы не сделали, оно не будет соответствовать действительности. Поэтому либо придумайте другой способ идентификации (куки?), либо ставьте лимит "от балды" и ждите жалоб от пользователей. Как появятся жалобы, так увеличивайте лимит раза в два/три/десять. И опять ждите жалоб и т.д.

Comment: Какие ещё жалобы? Можно легко собрать статистику количества запросов с одного IP в сутки и сделать косвенные выводы о примерном количестве пользователей за одним IP. Но я думаю вряд ли это изменит мои настройки "от балды": 1 запрос в секунду с одного IP к любым uri сервера со всплеском до 100 одновременных запросов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В связи с общей нехваткой ip адресов v4 в мире, такая практика распространена и постоянно нарастает. В один адрес пользователей собирают не только офисы, но и интернет-провайдеры. Провайдерам обычно выгодно собрать в один ip как можно больше пользователей, потому что все оставшиеся ip можно продавать как реальные адреса тем же абонентам и зарабатывать на этом.

Но есть физический лимит. NAT может одновременно пропустить на один ваш ip:порт не более 65536 соединений одновременно, потому что именно столько портов доступно в протоколах TCP и UDP. А NAT определяет кому предназначен ответный пакет именно по номеру порта.